# Как получать позицию элемента относительно окна браузера учитывая прокрутку?

Tags: javascript

Сейчас [есть такой код](http://codepen.io/smellyshovel/pen/gMapNO), и, казалось бы, он работает как надо:

```
elem.style.top = this._coords.tops[step] + "px";
elem.style.left = this._coords.lefts[step] + "px";
elem.style.width = this._coords.widths[step] + "px";
elem.style.height = this._coords.heights[step] + "px";
```

Блоки выделяются, по нажатию на next осуществляется переход на следующий блок. Короче говоря все отлично. Но есть одно НО (куда же без них?). Если перед началом скрипта (в данном случае триггером служит кнопка "Start" (чтобы на codepen не приходилось обновлять страницу каждый раз), а так - загрузка страницы) страница немного прокручена, то с самого начала выделяющий блок (с красной рамкой) немного смещен, а конкретно именно на столько, на сколько прокручена страница. Как избежать такого поведения?

То есть мне надо получать позицию (и ширину с высотой) текущего элемента (выделяемого), учитывая при этом прокрутку страницы. А точнее лучше даже сделать так, чтобы она ни на что не влияла (возможно, просто использовать альтернативную `getBudleClientRect()` функцию. Какую - **вопрос**).

---

**Нормальное поведение**
[image: Нормальное поведение]

---

**Поведение после прокрутки**
[image: Поведение после прокрутки]

---

**P.S. Весь код есть по ссылке вверху.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

34 строку замените, на эту: this._coords.tops.push(clientRect["top"] + window.pageYOffset);

Comment: Какое-то необычное поведение у меня на локальной машине. При начальной прокрутке размер выделяющего блока растет в геометрической прогрессии относительно дельты прокрутки.

Comment: А нет, извините. Просто добавил ко всему: и к высоте, и к ширине...  так работает на ура, благодарю.

Comment: А хотя нет, стоп. Попробуйте прокрутить страницу, а потом еще и нажать Next. Смещение проиходит вообще не туда, куда надо из за того, что нему еще прибавляется прокрутка. То есть при первом проходе такое работает, а при следующих уже некорректно.

Comment: Единственный костыль, что пришел в голову - это проверять, на какой итерации сейчас находимся. Если на первой, то выполнять ваш код, а если нет, то мой. Не очень красиво, однако, но работает. __P.S.__ Если сразу загрузить страницу, потом прокрутить ее вверх, а потом нажать Next, то вообще лажа. Так что извините, но решение, все-таки не очень хорошее.

Comment: this._coords.tops.push(clientRect["top"] + window.pageYOffset);
добавьте эту строчку сюда: Excursion.prototype.fillCoords
а там удалите

Comment: Если быть точнее, то 34 строку замените, на эту:
this._coords.tops.push(clientRect["top"] + window.pageYOffset);

Comment: Вроде пока что все нормально, благодарю. Я еще потестирую чуток, и, если все и будет хорошо, то отмечу это решением. Спасибо!